# How to stay on the same page of the jquery DataTable after refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

So I am using jquery plugin DataTable taken from https://datatables.net. Its a very interactive table and fulfils my requirements. The only problem is when I press a button on the webpage containing that table to perform some task, after the task is completed in the backend, it redirects to the same webpage. After the redirection happens, the table shows page 1 by default and not the page I was on before redirection.
How to correct this?

Comment: Can you please show the code relevant to the question. Also is the table inside a form tag?

Comment: You can use [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave). From the documentation: "_When enabled DataTables will store state information such as pagination position..._" See also [How to stay on the active page in jquery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599101/how-to-stay-on-the-active-page-in-jquery-datatable)